# Checking the Linear Independence of functions over an interval?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a function $y_1(x) = x^2$ and $y_2(x) = x|x|$, where $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$. Check if $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are linearly independent in the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$?

$$***$$

I began with:

$y_1(x) = x^2$ and $y_2(x) = -x^2$,  when x<0 and

$y_1(x) = x^2$ and $y_2(x) = x^2$,  when x>0

Let $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ be linearly dependent, then there exists scalars $\alpha, \beta$ (not all zero) such that $\alpha. y_1(x) + \beta. y_2(x) = 0$

In the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$,
$$\alpha.x^2 + \beta.(-x^2) = 0 , x \in (-\infty,0)$$
$$ and $$
$$\alpha.x^2 + \beta.(x^2) = 0 , x \in (0,\infty)$$

Here, I see that the functions are L.D. in intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$.

$$***$$

But, now I don't know how to proceed to see the linear independency of the functions over the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose they are linearly dependent. Then there are numbers $a,b$ nonzero such that $ay_1(x)+by_2(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Take $x=1$: $a\cdot 1+b\cdot 1 = 0$ and so $a=-b$.

Take $x=-1$: $a\cdot (-1)^2+b\cdot (-1)|-1| = a -b =0$, which means that $a=b$. Hence, $a=b=0$.